# split method of String class and for each loop not giving desired output

Tags: java, arrays, foreach

the following method sometimes returning true value, sometime false. Can someone please check what is the issue in this. The input to the method is "19"

```
public static boolean isStoreValid(String storeNo) {
    boolean isEnabled = true;
    try {
        String enabledStores = "9,18,43,44,32,38,19,37,23,29,34,31,17,20,3,5,6,7,8,10,21,24,25,26,11,12,14,15,16,22,27,28,30,33";
        String storeList = enabledStores.trim();
        String storeNoArray[] = storeList.split(","); 
        if (storeNoArray != null && storeNoArray.length > 0) {
            isEnabled = false;
            for (String store : storeNoArray) {
                if (storeNo.equals(store.trim())) {
                    isEnabled = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        } else {
            isEnabled = true;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        isEnabled = true;
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return isEnabled;
}
```

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: I am assuming that "method sometimes returning true value, sometime false." doesn't mean it returns different values for *same* input. So for what input you are getting results you ware not expecting? What ware you expecting there and why?

Comment: By default this method should return true if there is not store number available. From logs, it is not throwing any exception but it is returning true, sometimes false, happening in once in a while.

Comment: expected output is true. The input to the method is "19" and it is there in the String which is being splitted.

Comment: @Ashok When I run this method with input `19` it returns `true` as you expect. What's the issue here?

Comment: @Mark, yes i know it returns true even i don't see any issue in the logic but sometimes it is returning false 1 time out of 1000 runs may be with the same input. I checked the production logs. In logs, the return value printing is false with input 19.

Comment: @Ashok well, running the code `x` number of times doesn't really the change the output given the input is always "19". just to prove that I've tested your code with `Stream.generate(() -> isStoreValid("19"))
                .limit(1000)
                .anyMatch(x -> !x);` and this says there's no case in which the `1000` calls to `isStoreValid` returned `false`.

Comment: @Eugen, the String, we change it as per our requirements. I have added the exact value which is printing in the logs. I can not write the exact code here. The value It is coming from database. The same value is there in DB from last 7 days. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

1. What's *logically incorrect* is the `else` block, which should be a negation to the successful `if` block execution

   ```
   else {
       isEnabled = true;
   }
   ```

   change it to

   ```
   else {
       isEnabled = false;
   }
   ```

   meaning when there are no stores, you shall `return false` as the store wouldn't be valid.
2. There is no exception thrown by the code block shared by you, so you can easily get rid of the `try-catch`.
3. Instead of using the boolean flag, you can directly `return` from your blocks as :

   ```
   if (storeNoArray != null && storeNoArray.length > 0) {
       for (String store : storeNoArray) {
           if (storeNo.equals(store.trim())) {
               return true;
           }
       }
   } else {
      return false;
   }
   return false;
   ```
4. And further, if you would be interested to improve the readability, you can simplify as

   ```
   return Arrays.stream(storeNoArray)
                    .anyMatch(store -> storeNo.equals(store.trim()));
   ```

Comment: you don't need the `if/else` just `return Arrays.stream(storeNoArray)
                 .anyMatch(store -> storeNo.equals(store.trim()));` should suffice. if `storeNoArray` is empty `anyMatch` will return false.

Comment: @Aomine Correct, thanks...almost forgot following those steps about the `Arrays.stream` I was using.

Comment: We are using jdk 7.

Comment: @Ashok you can restrict yourself until step3 in that case.. the prime intention was the step1 to share this as an answer.

Comment: Thank you Aomine. I will follow up with the steps added by you and get back on this if i still see any issue.

Comment: @Ashok Since you are using JDK 7, please add a **java-7 tag** to your post.